# SignalR web client without ASP.NET?

Tags: signalr

Is it possible to write a WebSocket (SignalR) client without having to embed it in an ASP.NET application hosted on IIS (or other ASP.NET web server)?

For example if I have a Self Hosted SignalR Server with a custom Hub, is it possible (and if so, how) to call it from a "pure" Javascript web client?

In that case we don't have the `<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript" />` part with the run-time generated "magic" scripts in the `~/signalr/hubs/` folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to have an asp.net application for SignalR to work.  You can create a generic html page and still communicate with a SignalR server.  You can even utilize silverlight, windows phone or other clients to communicate with a SignalR server, there are plenty that are currently supported and even more that are third party developed (like android, ios, node etc.).

When you say "pure" JavaScript client I'm assuming you mean no third party libraries like JQuery, in this case SignalR currently does not work without JQuery but a client that does not depend on JQuery is in the pipeline (https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/372).

You can create a Self Hosted server pull down the SignalR by using ASP.NET **Owin**.

**Edit:**
In order to use self hosted servers you will have to enable cross domain in your application.  See the answer to: [SignalR: Error during negotiation request: undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990789/signalr-error-during-negotiation-request-undefined/14994041)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Still: how should a client side Javascript code look like to call a SignalR Hub method without using the scripts in `~/signalr/hubs/`? Using of jQuery is allowed and using SignalR module for jQuery (e.g. jquery.signalR-1.0.0.min.js) is also allowed.

Comment: So what I need is to "create a generic html page and still communicate with a SignalR server". Unfortunately I haven't found any docs about that.

Comment: Checkout the SignalR wiki.  Calling a hub method with no hub proxy & cross domain support: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs-%28No-Proxy%29. Note that cross domain also works with WebSockets.

Comment: @Osi you may also want to take a look at [SignalRUtils](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Utils) seems that you can generate the js by using the "GenerateHubProxyCommand" command.

Comment: How PHP people can use signalr...how they will be able to write hub code. i know they can connect to hub from their side by js but how they will be able to write hub code. thanks