# SignalR Self Hosting - why does IIS launch?

Tags: signalr, owin, self-hosting

I followed this tutorial on creating a SignalR app that doesnt need IIS...

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

However when I run it, the browser launches with this url in a tab...

```
`http://localhost:57719/Default.html`
```

and I can see in the taskbar that IIS Express has launched.

Can someone confirm that IIS should not launch (I assumed that I was creating a self contained app that didnt need IIS)?

Any ideas what I might have done wrong? (Please let me know what bits of code etc you need posted to help me figure this out.)

Comment: Are you using a web project or a console application....?

Comment: @dfowler, he SignalRSelfHost project is a consoleApp and the JavascriptClient is an empty ASP.NET web project with signalR installed and with a single HTML page

Comment: Then I have no idea what you're asking. You want to know how to server tatic files from the self host?

Comment: Yes, I want to serve up the initial page that contains the SignalR javascript, chat javascript etc, (once this page loads, the page's signalR will continue to communicate with the self hosted server). The tutorial that I followed causes IIS to launch - but surely the whole point of self-hosting is to host without needing IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out...

Delete JavescriptClient (the asp.net web project) from the solution as it is not needed if you just want to access the server from a web browser.

Follow the instructions in paragraph "Setting up Static Hosting and a JavaScript SignalR client" here ...

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=918

(Basically you need to install another package to allow the self hosted signalR server to server up pages).

Answer (score 1):

I've created project, added packages, copied code

I replaced this

```
   WebApp.Start(url)
```

with

```
WebApp.Start<Startup>(url)
```

It works fine without IIS.

I got exception with message

> The following errors occurred while attempting to load the app.
>    - No assembly found containing an OwinStartupAttribute.
>    - No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class.

When I start it with `WebApp.Start(url)`

I used .NET 4.5 project
Here are references after installing packages

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.2.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Cors">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Cors.2.1.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Cors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics.2.0.2\lib\net40\Microsoft.Owin.Diagnostics.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.2.0.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.2.0.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.2.0.2\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Check versions maybe there are issues with previous. Because with this libs code throw Exception, I described above.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  When I change the line you suggest I still get IIS launching

Comment: I'm non sure I understand what you mean by your answer. Are you saying that for you, if you change that line, th project works and IIS is not launched?

Comment: IIS is not launched in both cases. But when I tried to run project without changing this line WebApp.Start(url) the line throw exception. I found another examples of self-hosted signalR, there are everywhere is used generic method WebApp.Start<Startup>. So I changed line run project It works and IIS is not launched.

Comment: I've gone through the project again but cant for the life of me see what I've done wrong. Can you zip up your version and send me a link please?

Comment: rar VS2012 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6A33eN7kPvUZEhpVU9VTHZaVVE/edit?usp=sharing.

Comment: Thanks very much. The difference between your solution and mine was that you do not have the JavascriptClient project. When I deleted the JavscriptClient from my solution, I get the console App running and no IIS starting up. However now obviously, the chat function doesnt work (I just get a blank page appearing in the browser when I enter http://localhost:8080). Can you tell me why you didnt add the JavascriptClient project (or have I missunderstood something)?

Comment: Actualy I don't understand what did you want. You created Web Application started it and was surprised that it use IIS? SignalR is hosted in Console App, but you also started WebApp. So why do you trying to get access to hosted signalR via browser. You have to use it from js.

Comment: Here is client, from example that don't need IIS, you can just open html with browser https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6A33eN7kPvURkRGUEpZVjcwVEU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15115799/signalr-web-client-without-asp-net You can use different types of clients, in yor example, that you are researched client is written with js it uses appropriate js script jquery.signalR-2.0.1.min.js

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46047/discussion-between-daniel-grankin-and-spiderplant0)