# Signal R in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, signalr, swiftr

Hi iam trying to implement a swiftR in my chatting Application. I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR).

Iam continously getting this error

> Starting...
>
> ```
> Error: Optional(["message": Error during negotiation request.]) 
>
> Disconnected.
> ```

Here is my Swift code.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftR


class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    var simpleHub: Hub!
    var complexHub: Hub!
    
    var hubConnection: SignalR!
    var persistentConnection: SignalR!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Make sure myserver.com is mapped to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts
        // Or change myserver.com to localhost or IP below
        
        // Default is false
        SwiftR.useWKWebView = true
        
       
        
        // Default is .Auto
        SwiftR.transport = .auto
        
        // Hubs...
        hubConnection = SwiftR.connect("https://MYHUBURL HERE/") { [weak self] connection in

            
            self?.simpleHub = connection.createHubProxy("chatHub")
            
            
            SwiftR.startAll();

            
            // SignalR events
            
            connection.starting = {
                print("Starting...")
            }
            
            connection.reconnecting = {
                print("Reconnecting...")
            }
            
            connection.connected = {
                print("Connected. Connection ID: \(connection.connectionID!)")

            }
            
            connection.reconnected = {
                print("Reconnected. Connection ID: \(connection.connectionID!)")
            }
            
            connection.disconnected = {
                print("Disconnected.")
            }
            
            connection.connectionSlow = { print("Connection slow...") }
            
            connection.error = { error in
                print("Error: \(error)")
                
                // Here's an example of how to automatically reconnect after a timeout.
                //
                // For example, on the device, if the app is in the background long enough
                // for the SignalR connection to time out, you'll get disconnected/error
                // notifications when the app becomes active again.
                
                if let source = error?["source"] as? String , source == "TimeoutException" {
                    print("Connection timed out. Restarting...")
                    connection.start()
                }
            }
        }
        
        // Persistent connection...
        // Uncomment when using persitent connections on your SignalR server
        //        persistentConnection = SwiftR.connect("http://myserver.com:5000/echo", connectionType: .persistent) { connection in
        //            connection.received = { data in
        //                print(data!)
        //            }
        //        }
        
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
}
```

can someone help me to get connected to signR.

On github : https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR/issues/75

Comment: I think you can post an issue on he's github too. I used to have a problem and he answered me fast ! Hope you solve it

Comment: tnx for the suggestion. I will try to ask him on git hub.

Comment: You welcome. Make sure you don't use hub too

Comment: Sounds like the url is incorrect.

Comment: URL is correct. I used the same URL in Android application it works fine.

Comment: Check this link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990789/signalr-error-during-negotiation-request-undefined

Its not problem with client (iOS) I think. SignalR server failed to negotiate.
 Try SignalR server MapHubs to enable cross-domain

app.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });