# Is ASP.NET Core SignalR backwards compatible with ASP.NET SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

Is the ASP.NET **Core** SignalR server backwards compatible with an ASP.NET SignalR client?

I have a server implementation based on the old ASP.NET SignalR with PersistentConnection that I want to move to ASP.NET **Core** but old clients must still be able to connect to the new server platform - upgrading the clients is a slow process.

*This is a general question and I think it deserves its own post without the clutter of broken code.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connet to asp.net core signalR server from a javascript client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49300820/connet-to-asp-net-core-signalr-server-from-a-javascript-client)

Comment: It *should* be. Ultimately, it just boils down to web sockets, and any web socket-capable client should be able to work any web socket-capable server. Still, the best way to know for sure is to actually test it. If you have issues, you can then ask a specific question about that.

Comment: @ChrisPratt SignalR supports several modes of transport andd fallback between them. I have tested it and it does not work, I was wondering if it should or could work. The answer is no, SignalR is not backwards kompatible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no, and it is stated in the [this MSDN blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/)

*We added a number of new features to SignalR for ASP.NET Core but we also decided to remove support for some of the existing features or change how they work. One of the consequences of this is that **SignalR for ASP.NET Core is not compatible with previous versions of SignalR**. This means that you cannot use the old server with the new clients or the old clients with the new server. Below are the features which have been removed or changed in the new version of SignalR.*

Thanks @ATerry for pointing me to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311055/3230946)

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR. Detailed explanation is given into this [Microsoft Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1)